# How to draw a marker in middle of path?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a `path` (which is essentially a line). I am able to draw an arrowhead with the help of `marker-end` attribute of `path`. But now I want to make a `+` sign in the middle of the path. I think for that purpose, `marker-mid` should be used.

Here is the code and output when I use `marker-end`.
[image]

Here is the code and output when I use `marker-mid`.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`marker-mid` specifies the marker type that should be placed for the points in a path that are not the first or last point.

In other words, if you have a path that consists of four points (thus three lines), `marker-mid` markers will be placed on the middle two points.

There is currently no way to automatically place markers in the middle of a line segment as you wish.  You would need to either place an appropriate shape at that point yourself, or split the line into two half-lines.

SVG 2, which is still in development, will likely have this feature, but you can't do it yet.